# Внутренние отступы в toolbar android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-toolbar

Как динамически в коде изменить внутренние отступы в toolbar? Изначальные отступы задаю в xml:

```
        android:contentInsetStart="16dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="16dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="16dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="16dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="16dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="16dp"
```

Смысл в том, чтобы при нажатии кнопки обнулялись все отступы.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutInflater - класс, который генерит view объекты по xml. Посмотри его и LayoutParam
Можно [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams), а можно в поисковике по первым ссылкам увидеть их работу.